# PID Relay Controller Power Rating

Tags: power, ac, relay

I've used [this relay](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-industrial-automation-sales/AKT4R111100/6195883) to switch [this heat gun](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-11-6-Amp-120-Volt-Dual-Temperature-Heat-Gun-8975-6/100011623) in a heat box application with no issues (heating the box to 55C). One day the cover fell off and the heat gun ran continuously for a few minutes and burned up the relay. I didnt pick the parts for this but now am trying to replace with a PID relay with a higher power rating. Looking at the datasheet for the relay that got burned up it states 8VA. I dont have a fundamental understanding of AC power but luckily VA rating seem pretty straight forward. Pav = Irms*Vrms. Heat gun rating is 11.6A (im assuming to be RMS) and 120V. So 1392VA. I guess not surprising for a heating element.

But for the relay to state a power rating of 8VA? So if my understanding is correct then at 120V it can only handle and rms current of 8/120=0.066A_rms?

I must be wrong because this relay should have burned up a long time ago.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I read the datasheet:

The 8VA rating is the power consumed by the controller.

The relay contacts that you used to switch the power to the heater are only rated for 250 V 3 Amp - clearly inadequate to switch power to that heat gun.

You should find a relay with contacts rated for 120 V 12 A or more, with a 120 V coil, then have the PID controller control that relay rather than controlling the heat gun directly.

Comment: thank you. Your and spehro's answer cleared my understanding. I was beginning to think that using this PID controller to switch a separate relay so happy to know I was going down the right track.

Answer (score 5):

8VA is the power requirement of the entire controller.

The relay inside the controller has a 3A resistive rating and a life of only 100,000 operations at that current.

If you use the controller to switch something like a 12VDC 100mA coil relay with 30A rating both the controller and the relay should last a long time.

If you want to use a mains voltage relay, dig a little deeper to ensure the life will be adequate as the datasheet lists “resistive” rating and relay coils are inductive.

Comment: thank you that clears my understanding. I was beginning to think that using this PID controller to switch a separate relay so happy to know I was going down the right track.